# how Set OptionsMenu when certain fragment is shown

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my main Activity, I have a fragmentContainerView in which I am changing the fragments by using bottomNavigationbar which has 2 navigation Items (home & profile).
Now I want to show OptionsMenu the "profile" fragment is shown and then again remove it when the "home" fragment is shown.

How can I do it? or is there an alternative?

Comment: share your code snippet, plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a public method in the activity to change set the option menu and call it from the fragment like below.

```
HomeActivity homeActivity=(HomeActivity) getActivity();
assert homeActivity!=null;
homeActivity.yourPublicMethod();
```